# How can I render a block only if a specific route is active?

Tags: ember.js

I wanna render a block in Ember Handlebars only, if a specific route is active. 
So, how can I create a 'ifRoute' helper, with the same conditons then the 'active' class on the 'linkTo' helper?

I want this, because I've a two layer navigation. So, I want to show the sub-navigation only, if the head navigation point is active. I dont wanna use the 'active' class, because I use lazy loading and I only want to  load the sub navigation when the head navigation point is active.

So, what I want to do is:

```
<ul>
    {{#each assortmentGroups}}
        <li>
            {{#linkTo "assortmentGroup" this}} {{description}} {{/linkTo}}
            {{#ifRoute "assortmentGroup" this}}
                <ul>
                    {{#each itemCategories}}
                        <li>{{#linkTo "itemCategory" this}} {{description}} {{/linkTo}}</li>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
            {{/ifRoute}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
<ul>
```

How can I do this or is there a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating the ember code for the linkTo and if helpers, the answer from intuitivepixel and [a blog post about writing my own bound block helper](http://livsey.org/blog/2012/10/16/writing-a-helper-to-check-permissions-in-ember-dot-js/), I've found a solution:

```
var resolveParams = Ember.Router.resolveParams;

var resolvedPaths = function(options) {
    var types = options.options.types.slice(1),
    data = options.options.data;

    return resolveParams(options.context, options.params, { types: types, data: data });
};

Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('ifRoute', function(name) {
    var options = [].slice.call(arguments, -1)[0];
    var params = [].slice.call(arguments, 1, -1);
    var theResolvedPaths = resolvedPaths({ context: this, options: options, params: params });
    var router = options.data.keywords.controller.container.lookup('router:main');

    var self = this;
    var evaluateIsCurrentRoute = function() {
        self.set('current_route_is_active_bool_for_ifroute', (function() {
            return router.isActive.apply(router, [name].concat(theResolvedPaths)) ||
                router.isActive.apply(router, [(name + '.index')].concat(theResolvedPaths));
        })());
    };

    evaluateIsCurrentRoute();
    router.addObserver('url', evaluateIsCurrentRoute);

    options.contexts = null;

    return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.boundIf.call(this, 'current_route_is_active_bool_for_ifroute', options);
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Just add to the controller:

```
needs: ['application'], 
isCorrectRouteActive: Ember.computed.equal('controllers.application.currentRouteName', 'correctRoute')
```

Similarly:

```
isCorrectPathActive: Ember.computed.equal('controllers.application.currentPath', 'correct.path')
isCorrectURLActive: Ember.computed.equal('controllers.application.currentURL', 'correctURL')
```

I am quite sure latest Ember does the rest

Comment: Offtopic: DO heavily use Ember.computed.*

Comment: FYI - `needs` is deprecated in favor of `Ember.inject.controller`

Answer (score 4):

Here are two possible options, although for both you first have to save the `currentPath` in your `ApplicationController` to have access to it whenever you need it:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  currentPath: ''
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  updateCurrentPath: function() {
    App.set('currentPath', this.get('currentPath'));
  }.observes('currentPath')
});
```

### Using a computed property

Then in the controller backing up the template, let's say you have a `NavigationController` you create the computed property and define also the dependency to the `ApplicationController` with the `needs` API to gather access, then in the CP you check if the `currentPath` is the one you want:

```
App.NavigationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: 'application',
  showSubMenu: function(){
    var currentPath = this.get('controllers.application.currentPath');
    return (currentPath === "assortmentGroup");
  }.property('controllers.application.currentPath')
});
```

So you can use a simple `{{#if}}` helper in your template:

```
...
{{#linkTo "assortmentGroup" this}} {{description}} {{/linkTo}}
  {{#if showSubMenu}}
    <ul>
      {{#each itemCategories}}
        <li>{{#linkTo "itemCategory" this}} {{description}} {{/linkTo}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  {{/if}}
</li>
...
```

### Using a custom '{{#ifRoute}}' helper

But if your really want a custom helper to deal with your condition then this is how you could do it, note that the `currentPath` stored on your application is still needed since we need a way to get the value of the current route:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('ifRoute', function(value, options) {
  if (value === App.get('currentPath')) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  else {
    return options.inverse(this);
  }
});
```

And then you could use it like this:

```
...
  {{#linkTo "assortmentGroup" this}} {{description}} {{/linkTo}}
  {{#ifRoute "assortmentGroup"}}
    <ul>
      {{#each itemCategories}}
        <li>{{#linkTo "itemCategory" this}} {{description}} {{/linkTo}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  {{/ifRoute}}
</li>
...
```

See here also a simple Demo of the "custom helper" solution: http://jsbin.com/izurix/7/edit

> Note: with the second solution there is a catch! Since `bound` helpers do not support blocks (in embers handlebars customization) I used a simple helper that does not reevaluate the condition depending on bindings which is may not what you want.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hm, thanks, but that both looks more like work arrounds, then the best practice. But your answer has helped me alot to find a solution.

Comment: @Krutius, glad I could help, well the `currentPath` thing is best practice, the solutions per se might be workarounds.

Comment: the need to modify the application controller for this, makes me unhappy with this, so I cant make a module to inject this functionallity. So I've adapted the linkTo behaviour, and hope this ember internally does not use a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy way to check if a route is active, but to get this into a computed property may not be so easy.

```
// Test if you are currently in a route by it's lowercase name
App.isInRoute = function(name) {
    return App.Router.router.currentHandlerInfos.mapProperty('name').contains(name);
}
```

To use:

`App.isInRoute('posts.show'); // true if in the route`